# Perspective containing transforms, transition issue on Firefox quantum

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Firefox Quantum seems has an issue with transitioning transforms containing perspective. Please check this example in FireFox:
https://codepen.io/morteza-fsh/pen/JLdGOw

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const img = document.getElementById('img');
const transform = 'perspective(2000px) translateX(300px) translateZ(-1000px) rotate(360deg)';

img.style.transition = 'all 1s';
img.style.transform = transform;

btn.onclick = () => {
  if ( img.style.transform.length ) {
    img.style.transform = '';
  } else {
    img.style.transform = transform;
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle Animation</button>
<img id="img" src="https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/files/2017/12/firefox-logo-1000x1032.png" width="150" alt="">
```

Comment: why the perspecitve here ? why not simply scale ?

Comment: It's just an example to reproduce the issue